# Choosing database for a review app

Tags: database

In the next months, I'll be developing a review app as a my first "big" personal project. Here are some actions and features that it will have:

- Storing forms (text+images) which contain users' **review about an
  element** (an element could be a product, a service, a professional, etc).
- **Elements**:

  - are not related with each other
  - won't be more than 150 elements.
  - won't have more than 15 reviews each.
- Users can add image files to    the element review (up to ~3mb each),
  there will be no initial    limitation for the number of images that
  a review can have, but, the    number will be around 50 on the long
  run and never less than 5.
- Reviews can be deleted by the user and by admins.
- **All content will be moderated** (I need to check the quality of the uploaded data and it will be public just after it's accepted).

I'm a frontEnd guy with little experience (just a bit with SQL dbs), so, I don't have enough knowledge to evaluate what's best. For me, there's no difference between learning one or another type of db.

For what it's worth, the **app will have a AngularJS frontEnd and a Node.js backEnd**. Based on the research I've done, it was between MySQL and Postgres for SQL dbs, MongoDB and CouchDB for Document-Based NoSQL dbs and Neo4j as graph-based DB. So:

- Is there any advantage to using one or another type of database?
- Does any database match better with a nodeJS backEnd?